# Drupal 8. Error join() Twig function

Tags: 8, theming

I try to print `field_tags` inline and comma separated. My code in `node.html.twig`:

```
<p>{{ content.field_tags | join(', ') }}</p>
```

This return error message: `The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.`

Whats wrong? Help.

Comment: I doubt `content.field_tags` is a string...check your watchdog and server logs, the real error message should be in there

Comment: Nope. Is array from field taxonomy term list. If I print ``{{ content.field_tags[0] }}`` — response is first element from field.

Comment: There may be other way to analog ``<?php print implode(', ', $array); ?>`` from D7 for D8 Twig?

Comment: Oh sorry, I read "join" as "split" for some bizarre reason :) Are you sure `content.field_tags` is an array and not an object?

Comment: Even if the content.field_tags[0] renders properly, it does not mean it is a string. I suggest you check out the structure in preprocess function in php, not twig.

Comment: I would suggest using `dump()` or better yet get the devel module and enable the Kint sub module and do `{{ kint() }}` in your template. Also to get more helpful error messages make sure you set up the settings.local.php, see example.settings.local.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything in content is a render array, you can't use functions like that on those directory.

You can loop over it and print out each item, that works as it is then automatically rendered.

Comment: And you can check [`loop.last`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable) if you want to emulate the `join` filter.